# State.go() shows the url in address page but doesn't refresh the html view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem when whorking on Ionic with angularJs, the problem is in routing system when I try to develop a login page .
In the controller part of code i'l trying to load a welcome page calle 'dash' with `state.go(psc.dash)`

here is my **controller.js** :

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($location, $state) {
        var user = this;

        user.login = function() {
            console.log("LOGIN user: " + user.email + " - PW: " + user.password);
            setTimeout(function() {
                state.go('psc.dash');
            }, 20);
        };
    })
   .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $location) {});
```

here is my App.js:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'login': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('psc', {
    url: "/psc",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/psc.html"
  })
  .state('psc.dash', {
    url: "/dash",
    views: {
      'psc-dash': {
        templateUrl: "templates/dash.html",
        controller: "DashCtrl"
      }
    }
  })
  ;

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');    
});
```

and here is my **login.html**

```
<div class="list list col span_1_of_2 " ng-controller="LoginCtrl as loginCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">E-mail</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="loginCtrl.email">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">password</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="loginCtrl.password">
    </label>
    <div>
        <div class="col span_2_of_3"><a href="  ">forgot password ? </a></div>
        <button class="button button-positive  col span_1_of_3" ng-click="loginCtrl.login()">
            connect
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is when I click on connect button the url '/psc/dash' appears in address bar but the login view stay displayed and the page is not reloaded with the new html view.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
my psc route should be named 'login' to be identified

```
  .state('psc', {
url: "/psc",
 views: {
  'login': {
      abstract: true,
   templateUrl: "templates/psc.html"
  }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This is wrong. There is a discrepancy in the `ui-router` documentation: [states that inherit from an abstract state are prefixed with their parents URL](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples).

---

The reason is that although your `'psc.dash'` nested state is defined as a child of the `'psc'` state, the URL you have assigned to it is not automatically prefixed with its parent's URL.

You want to change the `'psc.dash'` state definition to this:

```
.state('psc.dash', {
    url: "/psc/dash",
    views: {
      'psc-dash': {
        templateUrl: "templates/dash.html",
        controller: "DashCtrl"
      }
    }
  })
```

Take a look at the [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) for why this is:

> **What Do Child States Inherit From Parent States?**
>
> Child states DO inherit the following from parent states:
>
> - [Resolved dependencies via resolve Custom data properties](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#wiki-inherited-resolved-dependencies)
> - [Custom `data` properties](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#wiki-inherited-custom-data)
>
> Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).

Comment: I changed it but is not a solution , it will show the "/psc/psc/dash" in the address bar of the navigator, but still not reload page.

Comment: You are also using a named view `'psc-dash'`. In your HTML, are you declaring a `<ui-view>` element with the `name` attribute? Like so: `<ui-view name="psc-dash"></ui-view>`

Comment: Yes, I added it in psc.html ,and I tried to add it in dash.html ass well, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I have in my Ionic command tab this message :
HTML changed: ...../psc.html 
Unable to update live reload: { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }

Answer (score 0):

The service is `$state` so the code should be:

```
$state.go('psc.dash');
```

You can get rid of the controller definition in your HTML:

```
<div class="list list col span_1_of_2" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as loginCtrl">

</div>
```

use this instead:

```
<div class="list list col span_1_of_2">

</div>
```

and change the state this way:

```
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'login': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl as loginCtrl"
      }
    }
  })
```

You don't need to define the controller twice.

Your **login.html** template does not use `<ion-view>`. It would be interesting to see a plunker of your project.

Another things I am not sure about is the state definition. If the view login is not wrapped in another container you should write it like this:

```
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
    controller: "LoginCtrl as loginCtrl"
  })
```

Comment: SOLVED, The problem was that my *psc* route has no name view in views .